# Find the Area of Rectangle that has Two similar triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, rectangles

A rectangle DEBC has triangle ABC.AB and AC intersect side DE at points F and G respectively. FG = 4, The perimeter of triangle ABC is double of the perimeter of Triangle AFG. The area of Triangle ABC = 16 sq units. What is the area of DEBC?

Comment: Is A in the interior or exterior of the rectangle.  What does a rectangle "having" a triangle mean?

Comment: If you can prove the triangles are symmetric then twice the perimeter means four times the area.

Comment: Sir/Madam, fleablood, The A is actually gets outside of the rectangle if you draw AB and AC lines from points B and C which has to intersects side DE at point F and G.

Comment: The two triangles has three similar angles which makes it similar triangle

Comment: "The A is actually gets outside of the rectangle if you draw AB and AC lines from points B and C which has to intersects side DE at point F and G"  Not if you extend $AB$ *past* $A$ and $AC$ *past* $A$ and they intersect $DE$ on the other side.

Comment: Not FG = $\frac 12 CB = \frac 12 DE$ so you can calculate the areas of all parts.  But do consider A interior as well as exterior.  It's the only way I can interpret the phrase "a rectangle *has* a triangle"

Comment: It's something like that Sir/Madam. The question says exactly "In triangle ABC,  AB and AC intersect side DE of rectangle DBCE at F and G points respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\Delta ABC\sim\Delta AFG$, we obtain:
$$\frac{S_{\Delta AFG}}{S_{\Delta ABC}}=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2,$$
which gives $$S_{\Delta AFG}=4$$ and since
$$\frac{S_{\Delta AFC}}{S_{\Delta AFG}}=\frac{AC}{AG}=2,$$ we obtain $$S_{\Delta AFC}=8.$$

Thus, $$4+8=S_{\Delta CFG}=\frac{4\cdot DC}{2},$$
which gives $$DC=6$$ and $$S_{DEBC}=6\cdot8=48.$$

Comment: I am sorry Sir but I can't understand what exactly did you mean by triangle "AFC" and Triangle "CFG"  also DC. It isn't actually matching with my depiction. Also can you please describe?The first line with clarification of above problems?

Comment: Sir An image of your depiction will be very helpful to understand.

Comment: @Ghost $CD$ is an altitude to side $GF$ from $C$ of the $\Delta CFG$. I don't know to draw in the net. I drew it by the given.

Comment: $S_{\Delta CFG}=S_{\Delta AFG}+S_{\Delta AFC}.$

Comment: Sir please can you send me a photo of the papers that you've used to draw.It will really helpful.